# SSL error in Ubuntu and Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, ssl

I am new to SSL, trying to enable it in Tomcat, but I have folowing error showing up by firefox, when accesing https://localhost:8443/:

```
An error occurred during a connection to localhost:8443.

SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.

(Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long)   

*   The page you are trying to view can not be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.

*   Please contact the web site owners to inform them of this problem. Alternatively, use the command found in the help menu to report this broken site.
```

The key type is PKCS12 and format .pfx, and it was generated by my local bank office, for future use.

Tomcat server.xml:

```
<Connector port="8443"
           maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
           maxThreads="150"
           minSpareThreads="25"
           maxSpareThreads="75"
           enableLookups="false"
           disableUploadTimeout="true"
           acceptCount="100"
           scheme="https"
           secure="true"
           clientAuth="false"
           sslProtocol="TLS"
           keystoreFile="key.pfx"
           keystorePass="mypassword"
           keystoreType="PKCS12"/>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tomcat 6 requires the parameter `SSLEnabled` of the [`Connector`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/http.html#Common_Attributes) tag to be set to true, in order to enable SSL. This is most likely the cause of the error reported by Firefox, for it might be receiving a HTML document in the response and attempting to read the supposed SSL payload off it.

Comment: I have enabled it, but now I'm getting this error: Certificate type not approved for application.

(Error code: sec_error_inadequate_cert_type)

Comment: @hoss, that's easy. Appears to be a problem with [the list of allowed activities for the certificate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364429/how-do-i-generate-an-ssl-certificate-with-microsoft-certificate-services-and-then). You might have to regenerate the certificate, if you can. Or get a new one issued.

Comment: I have regenerated it via certmgr.msc in Windows, but no luck :(

Comment: When you view the properties of the certificate, do you see that it allows for "Server authentication"?

Comment: In proprietes under "Enhaced Key Usage" I see "Client Authentication" only

Comment: Well, that's your problem. Firefox is authenticating the server, so the cert presented to it, should be allowed for use in Server authentication. I'm not very familiar with the Microsoft tools, but I'm pretty sure Technet would have an answer for you. I could only get this [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc740173(WS.10).aspx), but that might not help you.